# Lightning Component Create User and Error Handling

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a Custom Action on Contact object that calls a lightning component. This Lightning component calls on init an Apex Controller function to, based on the contact recordId, find the Contact details and then create a user based on those details. 
My problem is the following: I also want to handle an Exception, where if the Exception message is about existing username, i want to return to the component the user and then showing an input field with the value of User.Username. However, when i am on exception and throw an AuraHandledException, i cannot get the user's username. So, how could i get the user.Username from the returned message of the Exception ?
Code Below:

APEX CONTROLLER

```
//2020-05-08 @galaios Apex Class Controller for EnablePartnerUser Lightning Component

public without sharing class PartnerUserController {
    //Function that will create Automatically a user from Contact Record
    @AuraEnabled
    public static User createUserFromContact(String contactId) {
        User newCommunitiesUser;
        try {
            Contact objectContact = [SELECT FirstName,LastName,Email,AccountId 
                                 FROM Contact Where Id =: contactId LIMIT 1];

            COGNT__System_General_Settings__c system_sets = COGNT__System_General_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults(); //Get the organization default system settings to get the default profile

            //Select community profile that you want to assign
            Profile pf = [SELECT Id FROM profile 
                          WHERE name=: system_sets.COGNT__Partner_User_Default_Profile__c LIMIT 1];
            //Create user 
            newCommunitiesUser = new User(contactId=objectContact.Id, 
                                               username=objectContact.Email, 
                                               firstname=objectContact.FirstName,
                                               lastname=objectContact.LastName, 
                                               email=objectContact.Email,
                                               communityNickname = objectContact.LastName + '_'+Math.random(),
                                               alias = string.valueof(objectContact.FirstName.substring(0,1) + 
                                                                      objectContact.LastName.substring(0,1) + Math.random() ).substring(0,5), 
                                               profileid = pf.Id, emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
                                               languagelocalekey='en_US', 
                                               localesidkey='en_US', 
                                               timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');                  
            insert newCommunitiesUser;
            return newCommunitiesUser;
        } catch(DMLException ex) {
            if(ex.getDMLMessage(0).contains('Duplicate Username')) {
              //throw new AuraHandledException('[ERROR] Cannot enable communities access, a user with this email address already exists.');
              throw new AuraHandledException('Duplicate username: ' +newCommunitiesUser);
            } else {
                throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static boolean isAccountPartner(id contactId) {
        try {
            //Get the contact based on input id
            Contact objectContact = [SELECT FirstName,LastName,Email,AccountId 
                                     FROM Contact Where Id =: contactId LIMIT 1];
            //Get the Account record of the contact
            Account contactAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, isPartner from Account where id=: objectContact.AccountId];
            return contactAccount.IsPartner;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Exception occured: ' +e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

CMP

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global"
                controller="PartnerUserController">
    <!-- Handlers Declaration -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <!-- Define Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="spinner" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isDuplicateUsername" type="boolean" default="false"/> <!-- Defines whether isername is Duplicate so let user insert another username -->
    <aura:attribute name="communityUser" type="User" /> <!-- The created user record -->

    <!--Loading spinner section -->
    <div class="slds-is-relative">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.spinner}">
            <div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
                <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--large slds-is-relative" role="alert">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aura:if>
        <!--Loading spinner end-->
    </div>

    <aura:if  isTrue="{!v.isDuplicateUsername}" >
        <!--05/09/2019 George Galaios: Email1-->
            <!--Username--><lightning:input aura:id="username" type="email" placeholder="abc@domain.com" name="username" label="Username" value="{!v.communityUser.Username}" />
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER JS

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.spinner", true);
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.isAccountPartner"); //Call Apex to get the event
        action.setParams({"contactId" : recordId});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var State = response.getState();
            if(State==="SUCCESS"){
                var isPartner = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('is partner ' +isPartner);
                if (isPartner) {
                    var insertUser = component.get("c.createUserFromContact"); //Call Apex to get the event
                    insertUser.setParams({"contactId" : recordId});
                    insertUser.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                        var insertUserState = response.getState();
                        if(insertUserState==="SUCCESS"){
                            var returnedUser = response.getReturnValue();
                            console.log(returnedUser);
                            component.set("v.communityUser", returnedUser);
                            console.log(component.get("v.communityUser.Username"));
                            component.set("v.spinner", false);
                        } else if(insertUserState == "INCOMPLETE"){ //Case of Incomplete request
                            component.set("v.spinner", false);
                            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                            toastEvent.setParams({
                                "title": $A.get("$Label.c.Oops"),
                                "message": $A.get("$Label.c.No_interned_connection"),
                                type: "warning",
                                mode: "sticky"
                            });
                            toastEvent.fire();
                        } else if(insertUserState == "ERROR"){ //Case of error calling Apex method
                            component.set("v.spinner", false);
                            if (response.getError()[0].message.includes("Duplicate username")) {
                                console.log('Error message is: ' +response.getError()[0].message);
                                var errorWords = response.getError()[0].message.split(' '); //Slpit the words of the error message
                                console.log('error words length is: ' +errorWords.length);
                                console.log('User is: ' +errorWords[3]);
                                component.set("v.communityUser", errorWords[3].Username); //
                                console.log('after set to user!');
                                component.set("v.isDuplicateUsername", true); //set the isDuplicateUsername attribute to true in order to show the email field
                            }
                            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                            toastEvent.setParams({
                                "title": $A.get("$Label.c.Error"),
                                "message": response.getError()[0].message,
                                type: "error",
                                mode: "sticky"
                            });
                            toastEvent.fire();                    
                        }
                    });
                    $A.enqueueAction(insertUser);
                } else { //Account is not Partner
                    component.set("v.spinner", false);
                    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        "title": $A.get("$Label.c.Error"),  
                        "message": $A.get("$Label.c.Account_of_Contact_Not_Partner"),
                        type: "error",
                        mode: "sticky"
                    });
                    toastEvent.fire(); 
                }
            } else if(State == "INCOMPLETE"){ //Case of Incomplete request
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": $A.get("$Label.c.Oops"),
                    "message": $A.get("$Label.c.No_interned_connection"),
                    type: "warning",
                    mode: "sticky"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            } else if(State == "ERROR"){ //Case of error calling Apex method
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": $A.get("$Label.c.Error"),  
                    "message": $A.get("$Label.c.Account_of_Contact_Not_Partner"),
                    type: "error",
                    mode: "sticky"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();                    
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }        
})
```

Comment: I see you're trying to pass the entire user object through your error message:
throw new AuraHandledException('Duplicate username: ' +newCommunitiesUser);
What are you seeing on the client side, how is newCommunitiesUser received?

Comment: Hi EranV and thanks for the response. Yes, this is what i am trying to do. So the whole error message is seen on the client side as follows: Duplicate username: User:{ContactId=0035I000003bqeiQAA, Username=test1@gmail.com, FirstName=Andreas, LastName=Dokimopoulos, Email=test@gmail.com, CommunityNickname=Dokimopoulos_0.5703007217718055, Alias=AD0.8, ProfileId=00e5I000000pAGJQA2, EmailEncodingKey=UTF-8, LanguageLocaleKey=en_US, LocaleSidKey=en_US, TimeZoneSidKey=America/Los_Angeles}

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing the entire user object through your error message, you can pass only the username field:

Replace

```
throw new AuraHandledException('Duplicate username: ' +newCommunitiesUser);
```

With

```
throw new AuraHandledException('Duplicate username: ' +newCommunitiesUser.Username);
```